# Finding the partial derivative in a specific point

Tags: partial-derivative

I need help in finding the partial derivative in a specific point.

Let $x$, $y$, $u$ and $v$ be variables for which this relationship is true:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x^2 + xy - y^2=u \\ 
2xy + y^2=v \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
How do I find $(\frac{\partial x}{\partial u})_{v}$ for $x = 2$ and $y = -1$ ? As far as I know you need an expression for $x = x(u,v)$ in terms of only $v$ and $u$, right ?

Comment: What does the notation $(\frac{\partial x}{\partial u})_{v}$ stand for? (that $v$ there) And by the way, have you tried implicit derivation on each equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that

$$du = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}dy=(2x+y)dx+(x-2y)dy=3\,dx+4\,dy$$

$$dv = \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}dy=2ydx+(2x+2y)dy=-2\,dx+2\,dy$$

from here we can find

$$dx = \frac{\partial x}{\partial u}du+\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}dv$$

$$dy = \frac{\partial y}{\partial u}du+\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}dv$$